# Onion plot of a ball

Tags: plotting, regions, mesh

Consider the following simple example.

```
RegionPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
  MeshFunctions -> (Sqrt[#1^2 + #2^2 + #3^2] &), 
  Mesh -> {{0.25, .5, .75}}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], Axes -> False]
```

[image]

I would like to show some of the surfaces described by the mesh function which lie inside the ball. Is it possible to visualize only these surfaces?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** Post-process `RegionPlot` outputs to remove the walls:

```
colors = ColorData[97] /@ Range[4];
radii = {1, 3/4, 1/2, 1/4};
regionplots = RegionPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= #^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1},
     Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, Axes -> False] & /@ radii; 

Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], FaceForm[{Opacity[.5], #[[2]]}], 
  Cases[Normal[#[[1]]][[1]], _GraphicsGroup, All][[1]]}&/@Transpose[{regionplots, colors}],
  Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Alternatively, delete the `Polygon`s with constant `VertexNormals`:

```
Show[DeleteCases[Normal@RegionPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= #^2,
     {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1},
     BoundaryStyle -> None, Mesh -> None, BaseStyle -> Opacity[.5], 
     PlotStyle -> #2, Axes -> False], 
    Polygon[_, VertexNormals -> {{a_, b_, c_} ..}], All] & @@@ 
  Transpose[{radii, colors}], Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

You can use a combination of [`ImplicitRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html) and [`DiscretizeRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretizeRegion.html) as follows:

```
ir[r_] := ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == r^2, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}}]
radii = {1, 3/4, 1/2, 1/4};
colors = ColorData[97] /@ Range[4];
boundaries = RegionPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1.1,
  {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
  MeshFunctions -> (Sqrt[#1^2 + #2^2 + #3^2] &), 
  Mesh -> {Transpose[{radii, colors}]}, MeshStyle -> Thick, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0], Axes -> False, BoundaryStyle -> None];
i = 1;
surfaces = DiscretizeRegion[ir[#], 
  MeshCellStyle -> {{2, All} -> Opacity[0.5, colors[[i++]]]}] & /@ radii;
Legended[Show[surfaces, boundaries], 
  SwatchLegend[colors, "radius = " <> ToString[#, StandardForm] & /@ radii]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. In my concrete problem I only can build on (don't know why `ContourPlot` and `ImplicitRegion` don't evaluate) the result of `RegionPlot3D` to find the shells.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, does the approach in the update work in your  problem?

Comment: Yes , thanks for the two solution ideas!

Answer (score 8):

Like this?

```
ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1},
 ContourStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.5], ColorData[97][1]],
 Axes -> False,
 Contours -> {0.25, .5, .75},
 Mesh -> None
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes like this, thanks. But in my underlying problem I need to use the RegionPlot3D, because ContourPlot3D cannot evaluate.

Comment: Huh? You have to explain that to me...

Comment: Sorry my problem is quite complex, so I cannot post it. First I tried `ContourPlot3D[expr==dt,...]` for a special contour dt, but MMA runs forever. Thats the reason why I tried `RegionPlot3D[dt-.1<expr<dt+.1` in a range which includes dt.After some minutes MMA gives a result

Comment: Have you tried tweaking the `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` options of your `ContourPlot3D`? Often when MMA takes a long time to produce a plot, it's simply obsessing over detail you're not really interested in and it pays to reduce the values for these options.

Comment: @Sjoerd Smit Yes I tried `MaxRecursions-> 4` (same result) and `PlotPoints->50`(evaluation time increases dramatically) Thanks.

Comment: Trying `MaxRecursion -> 0` and `PlotPoints -> 25` is always a good start. The result will look very blocky, but the number of function evaluations should be low.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann The default for `MaxRecursion` is `2`, and time complexity, where significant refinement is called for, can grow exponentially.  E.g. `Table[First@
  AbsoluteTiming[
   ContourPlot3D[
    x^2 + Sin[6 y] + z^2 == 1, {x, -1.1, 1.1}, {y, -1.1, 
     1.1}, {z, -1.1, 1.1}, MaxRecursion -> r]],
 {r, 0, 4}]` --> `{0.096103, 1.23869, 4.76033, 20.5314, 118.243}`